# Complex Contribution and Membership

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

I'am setting CiviCRM for a new customer and I'm wondering about how to reach my goal:
1 individual owns 1 or more companies that have/own 1 or more sub-entity (shop) knowing that the membership contribution will vary depending on the number of Companies owned and the number of Shops. There is not pre-defined pattern. You just can't have a Shop without having a Company. Only a company can get a membership.

I have set 3 profils with the necessary customs fields:
Owner (based on Contact)
Company (based on Organization)
Entity (based on Organization)

I have created the relationships between Owner (owns) and Company (is owned) and between Company (owns) an Entity (is owned).

I have created the 6 different prices set (which I am not sure to be the right way).

I have allowed in the contribution the owner to get membership on behalf of a company.

I don't find the way in a webform to create new company depending on the number of Companies.

I have read these posts: [post 1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/how-to-get-subsidiary-membership-to-work),[post 2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25715/creating-complex-structure) and [post 3](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6548/creating-other-relationships-for-memberships-on-behalf-of-an-organization) and also the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/membership-price-sets/):

I am a bit confused now and wonder if I am in the right direction? 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21173/how-to-build-a-drupal-webform-for-individual-organization-contributors

Comment: I will have a look. thanks for the link!